# How to show multiple tags(Textview) on screen when tap on screen in Android..?

Tags: android, dynamic, view

I want to show multiple tags of textview on screen when i will touch the screen. Right now I am using tags(Textview) that I have created in xml but is it not possible to create mulitple tags in xml. Is there any way to create multiple tags dynamically?
My code:

```
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event)
{
show tag();
}

    private void showTag() {
            if(tagFlag==0)
            {
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams params = ((AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams) _tagLiley.getLayoutParams());
                params.x = (int) tagX;
                params.y = (int) tagY;
                _tagLiley.setLayoutParams(params);
                _tagLiley.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  
                tag1=_categorySearchET.getText().toString().trim();
                _tagName.setText(tag1);
                _tagName.setTextSize(8);
                tagFlag=1;
            }
            else if (tagFlag==1) {
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams params = ((AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams) _tagLiley2.getLayoutParams());
                params.x = (int) tagX;
                params.y = (int) tagY;
                _tagLiley2.setLayoutParams(params);
                _tagLiley2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tag2=_categorySearchET.getText().toString().trim();
                _tagName2.setText(tag2);
                _tagName2.setTextSize(8);
                tagFlag=2;
            }
            else if (tagFlag==2) {
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams params = ((AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams) _tagLiley3.getLayoutParams());
                params.x = (int) tagX;
                params.y = (int) tagY;
                _tagLiley3.setLayoutParams(params);
                _tagLiley3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tag3=_categorySearchET.getText().toString().trim();
                _tagName3.setText(tag3);
                _tagName3.setTextSize(8);
            }
        }
```

Comment: @SpringBreaker  I am beginner. and I dont have that much knowledge. if u having answer of my question then help me.

Comment: What is the tag that you want to display?

Comment: Do you want to display a `TextView` where you touch on the screen ?

Comment: at any where of screen

Comment: Use Canvas for that......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to display text in a `TextView` at the touched place of the screen.Use the below code,

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/Relative"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

    RelativeLayout rel;
    TextView text;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        rel=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.Relative);
        rel.setOnTouchListener(this);

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
        int eventaction = e.getAction(); 
        int x,y;
          switch (eventaction ) { 
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:{ // touch on the screen event
                     x = (int)e.getX();
                    y = (int)e.getY();

                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:{ // move event
                   x = (int)e.getX();
                   y = (int)e.getY();



                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:{  // finger up event
                    x = (int)e.getX();
                       y = (int)e.getY();
                       text=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
                       lp.topMargin=y;
                       lp.leftMargin=x;
                       text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                       text.setTextSize(20);
                      text.setText("("+x+","+y+")");
                      rel.addView(text, lp);
                    break;
                }
              }
        return false;

    }

}
```

Hope it helps.